# Firefox sessions lost after last update

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-gnome, session

I updated my Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 a few hours ago. Upon opening Firefox I lost all opened tabs.

Here's are the contents of the `sessionstore-backups` directory:

```
aug.  14 02:57 upgrade.js-20170612122310
aug.  16 20:35 upgrade.js-20170814194055
aug.  20 11:18 upgrade.js-20170816210634
oct.   1 02:47 previous.js
oct.   2 17:53 recovery.bak
oct.   2 17:54 recovery.js
oct.   3 17:34 previous.jsonlz4
oct.   3 17:35 recovery.baklz4
oct.   3 17:35 recovery.jsonlz4
```

I tried copying the following

```
oct.   1 02:47 previous.js
oct.   2 17:53 recovery.bak
oct.   2 17:54 recovery.js
```

to the following

```
oct.   3 17:34 previous.jsonlz4
oct.   3 17:35 recovery.baklz4
oct.   3 17:35 recovery.jsonlz4
```

but I can't seem to recover the session.

PS: I have 3 profiles and I had already opened 2 of them. Both have the same problem.

Can I still recover my sessions?
And what can I do for the 3rd profile to ensure I restore my session?

**Update**: I opened the third profile which did add-ons update and luckily my tabs where still there. So basically I lost my sessions for the first 2 profiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This procedure worked for me.

- Close Firefox
- Backup `sessionstore.js` file and `sessionstore-backups` directory:

  ```
  $ cp sessionstore.js sessionstore.js.0
  $ cp -r sessionstore-backups sessionstore-backups.0
  ```
- Remove `sessionstore.jsonlz4` from profile directory as well as all `*.jsonlz4` files from `sessionstore-backups` directory.

  ```
  $ rm sessionstore.jsonlz4
  $ rm sessionstore-backups/*.jsonlz4
  ```
- Copy `recovery.js` from `sessionstore-backups` to `sessionstore.js` in profile directory:

  ```
  $ cp sessionstore-backups/recovery.js sessionstore.js
  ```
- Start Firefox. My last saved session was correctly restored.

Source: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1173678